Choosing between newtx or combined newtxtext and newtxmath
I am encountering some confusion regarding when to use the newtx package versus the combined newtxtext and newtxmath.
For example, when I use newtx along with the mtpro2 v. lite font, I get an error related to the integral glyph—it
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
Questa parte verrà trattata con gli integrali definiti.
        \[V(B)=V(A)-\frac{L_{A\to B}}{q_0} \iff \varphi(B)-\varphi(A)=-\int_A^B \overline E\cdot \Delta \bar r \iff \varphi(B)=\varphi(A)-\int_A^B \overline E\cdot \Delta \bar r\]
        generalizzando se $A$ (fisso) e $P$ (punto variabile), 
        \[\varphi(P)=\varphi(A)-\int_A^P \overline E\cdot \Delta \bar r\]
\end{document}


shows up as a strange character "�" during the compilation.
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\untxmia.fd)
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\untxsym.fd)
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\untxsyc.fd)
Overfull \hbox (47.29356pt too wide) detected at line 7
\LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 V.B/ \LMP2/mtt/m/n/12 D \LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 V.A/ \LMP2/mtt/m/n/
12 ^^@ []  �  \LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 '.B/ \LMP2/mtt/m/n/12 ^^@ \LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 '.A
/ \LMP2/mtt/m/n/12 D ^^@ [][] [] ^^A \LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 �[]  \LMP2/mtt/m/n/12 � 
 \LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 '.B/ \LMP2/mtt/m/n/12 D \LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 '.A/ \LMP2/mtt/m/n
/12 ^^@ [][] [] ^^A \LMP1/mtt/m/it/12 �[]

However, this issue does not occur when I use newtxtext instead of newtx and \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}.
My questions are:
When should I use newtx (the single package) instead of combining newtxtext and newtxmath (or mtpro2 lite)?
Is there any reason or benefit to using them together, or should I be cautious of potential compatibility issues?
How can I avoid these glyph errors when combining newtx and mtpro2, lite?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

You shouldn't expect math font packages using different font encodings to work together "out of the box" it may in some cases be possible to load both font sets but you would have to expect to adjust the tex commands to choose the right fonts and characters in each case.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for your kind response, I warmly welcome your answer. Thanks again.

the erroneous output isn't directly related to the strange character in the console output: you get that with just newtx. newtx says: Package to simplify loading of newtxmath with a text font family such as newtxtext for all latex engines, or for newtxtext and an otf math package.

@cfr Thank you again. But what is the reason to use newtx?

with text fonts, you tend to be loading a font more specifically with a certain encoding. so you are more likely to get an error, missing character or substitute than the wrong character. but for maths, the encodings and definitions work differently because most of the maths characters are defined via alphabet or symbol font definitions. so if you change from one encoding to another and don't tell latex how to adapt, you just get the wrong character.

based on what the package itself says, I think it is just providing an interface to newtxtext/newtxmath. so the reason to use it at all will be the same as the reason to use those packages i.e. you want particular fonts. the reason to use it rather than using those packages may be a simpler interface or could be to combine with an otf maths setup. however, you absolutely shouldn't use it in combination with an otf maths setup, so I would eliminate that reason.

The overfull box message is irrelevant for the problem: it just tells you that the first math display is too wide.
Let's look at what happens:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}

Questa parte verrà trattata con gli integrali definiti.
\begin{align*}
  V(B)=V(A)-\frac{L_{A\to B}}{q_0}
  &\iff
  \varphi(B)-\varphi(A)=-\int_A^B \overline{E}\cdot \Delta \bar{r} \\
  &\iff
  \varphi(B)=\varphi(A)-\int_A^B \overline{E}\cdot \Delta \bar{r}
\end{align*}
generalizzando se $A$ (fisso) e $P$ (punto variabile), 
\[
  \varphi(P)=\varphi(A)-\int_A^P \overline{E}\cdot \Delta \bar{r}
\]

\texttt{\expandafter\string\the\textfont3}

\texttt{\meaning\int}

\texttt{\meaning\intop}

\end{document}


The last three “cryptic” instructions show the font used for large symbols (where integral symbols are taken from) and the definition of \int and \intop that are responsible for printing the symbol: it will be an operator (first digit 1), taken from \textfont3 using the slot AF.
Let's look in mtpro2.sty: we first find
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}

which corresponds to what's printed in the example above. However, replacing \usepackage{newtx} with just \usepackage{newtxtext} we get

Can you see now what goes wrong? Yes, the slot the integral symbol is taken from is different.
The LMP3 font encoding is (almost) the same as the standard OMX encoding (that is, cmex10) for the lower half of the character set, but differs in that it also uses the upper half (slots from 128 to 255).
On the other hand, newtxmath does a different thing, namely
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}

A different font encoding altogether, but with a very different layout from `OMX. And indeed, we find
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\intslop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"AF}

Do you see AF? Yes, that's where it comes from.
What happens is that loading newtx, the package newtxmath is loaded to do the math font setup and \intop is redefined to be \intslop which in turn points to the largesymbols font at slot "AF. When mtpro2 is loaded, it does nothing special for \intop, because it assumes the symbol points to the standard location in largesymbols. Well, no. And you get what LMP3/mtt/m/n/12 has at slot "AF, which happens to be a big brace.
Does this make sense?
Yes. It used to be necessary to load separately newtxtext and newtxmath if one wanted this variety of Times for both text and math; the latter package has a wealth of options that don't really make sense for newtxtext. However, quite recently, Michael Sharpe provided newtx in order to avoid the double loading.
But this doesn't mean that you can decide for a different math font later. If you do want NewTX for text and MTPro2 for math, you must do
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

because, as we've seen, newtxmath and mtpro2 clash with each other.
Final word
Don't use \overline E or \bar r. It should be \overline{E} and \bar{r}. However, \overline{E} results in a very bad output:

The first is \overline{E} (ugly), the second is \,\overline{\!E} (bad) and the third is \bar{E} (good).
Full example
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

Questa parte verrà trattata con gli integrali definiti.
\begin{align*}
  V(B)=V(A)-\frac{L_{A\to B}}{q_0}
  &\iff
  \varphi(B)-\varphi(A)=-\int_A^B \bar{E}\cdot \Delta \bar{r} \\
  &\iff
  \varphi(B)=\varphi(A)-\int_A^B \bar{E}\cdot \Delta \bar{r}
\end{align*}
generalizzando se $A$ (fisso) e $P$ (punto variabile),
\[
  \varphi(P)=\varphi(A)-\int_A^P \bar{E}\cdot \Delta \bar{r}
\]

\end{document}



Your explanation was clear, detailed, and very helpful, and it really made a difference in understanding the problem. I truly appreciate the time and effort you put into helping me out. Thanks again!
